# Javascript - How should I get values from inbetween two quotes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Alright, so I'm using Node.JS for a discord bot. I am trying to get values from in between quotes. Here's an example -

!move "Channel One" "Channel Two"

The values in between the quotes may change. I would like to store these values in a variable for use in other lines of code.

Comment: You mean you want to sort out "one" versus "two"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to loop through the string and capture the values you want:

```
let strValue = '!move "Value one" "Value two" "Value three" "Value four"';
let regex = /"([^"]*)"/g;
let currentResult;
let results = [];
while ((currentResult = regex.exec(strValue)) !== null) {
    results.push(currentResult[1]);
}
// results: ["Value one", "Value two", "Value three", "Value four"]
```

Comment: What if I wanted to pass in `"Value \"one\""`?